CMake targets are not exported before add_subdirectory is called
I have an app, an interface library and plugins.
I define the targets in the main lists file.
Plugins are included using add_subdirectory(plugins).
I want plugins to be able to use find_package in the build and install tree.
I exported targets like this
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

set(LIB_EXPORT_NAME AlbertTargets)
set(LIB_TARGETS_FILE "${LIB_EXPORT_NAME}.cmake")
set(LIB_CONFIG_FILE "AlbertConfig.cmake")
set(LIB_VERSION_FILE "AlbertConfigVersion.cmake")
set(LIB_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(INSTALL_CONFIGDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Albert")

# Install the target
# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets
install(
    TARGETS ${TARGET_LIB}
    EXPORT ${LIB_EXPORT_NAME}  # just an association
    FRAMEWORK DESTINATION .
    INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/albert
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

# Create version file in build tree
write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${LIB_VERSION_FILE}"
    VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION}"
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

# Create config file in build tree
configure_package_config_file(
   "${LIB_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR}/${LIB_CONFIG_FILE}.in"
   "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${LIB_CONFIG_FILE}"
   INSTALL_DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)

# Create a targets file in install tree
# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#export
# By default the generated file will be called <export-name>.cmake
install(
    EXPORT ${LIB_EXPORT_NAME}
    # NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)

# Create a targets file in build tree (matching install(EXPORT))
# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html#exporting-targets-matching-install-export
# Seems like a shorthand for export(TARGETS)
export(
   EXPORT ${LIB_EXPORT_NAME}
   # NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
   FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${LIB_TARGETS_FILE}"
)

install(FILES
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${LIB_CONFIG_FILE}"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${LIB_VERSION_FILE}"
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)

# Add bin dir to the prefix path such that plugins in the source tree
# can find albert using find_package
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")

However when building the project in the build tree cmake complains about the missing targets file.
If I comment the add_subdirectory(plugins) line the targets file is created.
Is add subdir preferred over export(EXPORT?
What can I do to export the targets before the plugins are processed?
Or in general how can I achieve that the plugins are able to call find_package(…) to find the interface library in the build tree or on the system?

The export command is about using project targets from outside, not within the currently configured project. For make find_package to work in the currently configured project you may create all needed targets and provide some FooConfig.cmake script just for make find_package "happy". You may create such script in the directory CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_REDIRECTS_DIR. Or you may create such script in any other directory and add this directory to the search list of find_package.

Should it work if i make a super project and call add subdirectory for each target then?

I am not quite understand what do you actually want, but in CMake targets are global. So a target defined inside add_subdirectory call will be visible under another add_subdirectory.
